# transposing a dataframe inside a fuction in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a very large df that needs to be filtered, grouped, summarized, and rearranged for further processing by a different program.  I can do it one line of code at a time, but I need to generalize. The starting data frame has this format:

| uniqueID | year | header_1 | header_2 | m | n | etc. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 1990 | x | TRUE |  |  |  |
| 0002 | 1990 | y | FALSE | other data |  |  |
| 0003 | 1995 | x | FALSE |  |  |  |

the final result should be like this, for a single year y in df d, where a = header_1 and b = header_2:

| header_1 | TRUE | FALSE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | count(x) | count(x) |
| y | count(y) | count(y) |
| z | count(z) | count(z) |

```
    slice <- function (d,y,a,b) {
       t <- filter(d, year %in% c(y))
       c1 <- group_by(t, {{a}}, {{b}}) %>%
         summarise(count = n())

       c2 <- c1 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = {{a}}, values_from = count)
       
       h <- c2$a
       c3 <- as.data.frame(t(c2[,-1]))
       colnames(c3) <- h

      }
```

I'm getting Error: Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names. In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `a`.

Again, I'm not sure why this works if I explicitly name the objects, but breaks if I try to substitute a variable.
I kind of understand the uninitialized column 'a' at line 6 and I tried applying double curly brackets in several ways (including around all of lines 6 to 8), but I must be putting them in the wrong place.  Also tried inserting an explicit statement to name the rows like so:

```
   c3$name <- factor(row.names(c2))
```

but can't seem to make progress on the transposition error. Appreciate any light that can be shed.

edited to add sample data:

```
    id <- c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007")
    year <- c(1990, 1990, 1995, 2000, 1995, 2000, 2000)
    header_1 <- c(x, y, x, z, y, z, x)
    header_2 <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
    d <- data.frame(id, year, header_1, header_2)
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data in an appropriate format?

Comment: of course, sample data added

Comment: First you should replace ``h <- c2$a`` by ``h <- select(c2, {{a}})``, otherwise you have no access to your variable ``a`` within the function. However, based on your sample data it does not make sense to select ``a`` here since it will not be present in the df after your processing steps. If you replace ``a`` by ``b`` at this point you will receive an output, although it's not the result you might expect. Thus, you need to adjust your processing steps.

Comment: that is helpful, thank you.  However, I'm afraid I don't understand the point about 'a' not being present in the final df. I'm grouping by 'a' and 'a' is the name of the index column in the final df ( a = header_1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using examplary the year 2000, here's a solution which generates the structure you want to have:

```
slice <- function (d, y, a, b){
       c2 <- filter(d, year %in% c(y)) %>% 
         group_by({{a}}, {{b}}) %>%
         summarise(count = n()) %>% 
         pivot_wider(names_from = {{b}}, values_from = count)
}

df <- slice(d, 2000, header_1, header_2)
```